# Call Javascript File located in JAR - Eclipse

Tags: java, javascript, eclipse, jar, project

I have a Java project with a couple of JS (Javascript) files. The structure of the project is like this:

```
JSProj
  JSLib1
    JSFile1.js
  JSLib2
  JSLib3
```

And, I have other project, a JAVA Web project, like this one:

```
JAVAProj
  WebContent
    jsScriptsFolder
    index.html
```

The "index.html" needs to use some JS files from the other project. I want to use both ones without copy JS Project content inside the Java Project.

My first aproach was to make a Linked folder inside the "jsScriptFolder", but, was necessary to add one by one, or add an other level of folder.

Is there any way to use the JS project as a Java project? Link it, and use it? Can I export it to a JAR file and use it inside the JAVA Proj?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Can't you reference the javascript files from the other application using their full name? (so http://website.com/js/jquery.js?)

Comment: The other project is not an application, is just a project that I use as JS container.